# Are statistics and achievements global or not?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

Are Minecraft statistics and achievement stored somewhere on Mojang servers, or are they stored only locally on my computer? For example - if I logged into Minecraft on my friends computer, will statistics and achievements be "synced" and visible there? If not, does someone know if it's somewhere on devs to-do list?

Comment: so no one else can look at your stats

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are stored locally, as explained on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievements):

> You can reset all of your Achievements by deleting the "stats" folder in the .minecraft app data folder. (WARNING: Also resets Statistics)

Comment: This is going to change in the future, however. :)